# Website will not load on iPad or iPhone but loads great everywhere else

Tags: php, macos, safari, loading

I built https://billmykids.com recently and launched it.  However the site will not load on an iPad or iPhone.  I tried Safari and Chrome but both just hang and never load the site.  The site loads fine on an android phone and a PC.

Any ideas?

Comment: BTW, I have tried rebooting, resetting the Wifi, clearing the cache.  None of it made a difference.  Other websites load fine on my iPad.

Comment: Which iOS version you are using in iPad?

Answer (score 1):

I tried going to the site on my iPhone X and was able to reach the site fairly quickly on both chrome and safari.

Have you tried going into private browsing/incognito mode on both?

Another thing you can do if you have a Mac is to download the developers version of safari https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/ and plug your device into your computer to see if the device is throwing any error/console messages along with looking at the network tab.

Other than that, without seeing more or knowing what the errors are, I'm not sure that I can do much more to help.

Comment: Sadly I do not have a Mac.

Comment: What iOS are you using? I can try and use a device with the same iOS and plug it into mine to see if I get any errors

Comment: I am not using iOS.  The site is running on raspbian linux and is developed in a PHP platform called WaSQL.  I am trying to test the site on my iPad running iOS 11.4.1

Answer (score 1):

It loads fine on Safari5.1.7 on Win7 64-bit however there is an error message in the console: `/php/minify_js.php?_minify_=materialize_M360499812P1T2TI1127656722V1:1422 SyntaxError: Expected an identifier but found 'tlist' instead`.

I've found Apple browsers to be particularly fussy about syntax errors - one of my sites didn't work on Safari until I fixed a trivial error that other browsers (Chrome/Firefox/IE) all ignored.

Comment: ran my js through lint and fixed a few but still nothing

Comment: That made a huge difference to how it looks on Safari. I hadn't realised there was supposed to be text below the images. Now there's just a couple of (ignorable) warnings about Resources transferred with the wrong MIME type: logo.svg (image/svg+xml) and wasql_icons.ttf (application/font-sfnt).

Comment: You might still be getting the old cached version on your iPad. Did you clear all the stored data for the browser?

Comment: I will have my friend with a Mac try it in developer mode and see if she can find anything.  She also had the same problem on her iPhone.